# Photoshop: how to do a gradient fade with pattern

Tags: photoshop, fade

I want to create an image where the pattern fades out closer to the middle.

So the as it goes from middle of the image to the sides the pattern get more opacity.

The attached image is what I have so far. Basically instead of blue colour I want to have hexagons fading out as it gets closer to the middle.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: This question if off topic for Stack overflow as it does not concern programming or scripting. You would be better off asking on the [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). That said the effect you're looking for can easily be achieved by putting your pattern on a separate layer and using a layer mask.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create the pattern on a layer, then apply a "gradient fade" effect (last one on the list) on that layer. Set the gradient to "radial" and you're golden.